# Why cant Activator.CreateInstance find the constructor?

Tags: c#, activator

I am loading a DLL up at runtime.  The DLL and the main application both use a DLL witch holds interfaces that let the program know how to use some of the Types in the DLL.  In the main application there is a Factory class where the Dll can set one of its object types to be created when the main application requests the interface it inherits from. below is the striped down (mainly removed error handling code) version of the function to create the object type from the DLL.  When this gets called I get a Exception saying no parameterless constructor defined for this object.  I dont know why because they all have parameterless constructors.

```
    //inside the DLL
    Factory.ResovleType<ISomething>(typeof(SomethingCool));

    //inside the main application
    ISomething obj = Factory.CreateObject<ISomething>();


    //inside the Factory Class
    public static T CreateObject<T>(params object[] args) 
    {
        T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(resovledList[typeof(T)], args);

        return obj;
    }

    public static void ResolveType<T>(Type type)
    {
          resovledList.Add(typeof(T), type);
```

Comment: Is the constructor visible(public) to this method?

Comment: Yes all construtors are public classname() so they are visible and have no parameters

Comment: Can you provide the constructor code of the object you are try to create plus the code that is calling CreateObject?

Comment: Post some code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Also please post the full exception details.

Comment: What does `resovledList[typeof(T)]` contain?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen resovledList is a Dictionary<Type, Type>

Comment: @Shredder2500 But what does it contain? Which type is being found? One way it could be going wrong is if it's trying to instantiate a different type than you're expecting, and that different type doesn't have an appropriate constructor.

Comment: @hvd when I log out the type its trying to create it says runtimeType could that be the problem?

Comment: @Shredder2500 Yes, that could well be it, that suggests you're doing something like calling `ResolveType<ISomething>(typeof(Something).GetType())` (where the `GetType()` is wrong)

Comment: @hvd nope only have typeof(Something) and never typeof(Something).GetType() just doubled checked

Comment: So just to make sure, you verified both that `ResolveType` is never called with `RuntimeType` as its argument, yet `resovledList[typeof(T)]` is `RuntimeType`? Based on the code you've shown, that shouldn't be possible (at least not if `resovledList` is not modified by any other methods).

Comment: I think I found it the getType wasn't on the ResolveType<ISomething(typeof(Something)) but was in my actual resovleType method.  I typed resovledList.Add(typeof(T), type); in the question here and that is what It should have been but in the actual function i typed resovledList.Add(typeof(T), type.GetType); thaks for you help hvd if you want to post that as an answer ill accept it

Comment: Heh, glad you found it, that would have been hard to find for anyone else who only sees what you put in the question. :)

Comment: Yeah, i didnt feel like copy and pasting because I didnt want to have to worry about sriping it down so i just wrote it how it was, or I thought it was hehe.  that was more of a typo than anything I shouldn't write code late at night I guess :P thanks again for helping me find that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

The type that's found by `resovledList[typeof(T)]` isn't the intended type. Instead, it's `RuntimeType`. This would be a likely result of calling `ResolveType<ISomething>(typeof(Something).GetType())` instead of `ResolveType<ISomething>(typeof(Something))`:

`typeof(Something)` is a value of type `Type` (actually `RuntimeType`, which derives from `Type`), so calling `typeof(Something).GetType()` gives you `typeof(RuntimeType)`.

As it turned out, you were actually calling `GetType()` somewhere else, but the problem and solution are the same: you shouldn't call `GetType()` here.